# Security best practice: revoke execution (-x) permissions for directory, or do recursively to change every contained file?

Tags: security, permissions, best-practices, chmod

I have a question about security best practice when configuring a device to be used to users, who should be able to use a programme, but not modify the system.

Let's say I have a folder `/opt/myapp` containing numerous files that my programme reads. To avoid the user learning too much about the internals of my software, I don't want the user to have access to these files (and I note, the software itself doesn't write anything to this directory either).

Assume the folder has owner/group that's different from the user account. Thus: running `chmod o-rwx /opt/myapp` removes all "Others" permissions, so the user cannot navigate into that directory. Therefore, they won't be able to see the files.

However, I note I could also alternatively execute this command recurisvely, to revoke permissions on all files within the folder too. But since the user can't `cd` into that directory, is this relevant?

My question is: which is the better solution? Is there any real-world difference or best practice here?

Comment: A running program generally has the same permissions as the user running it. That means that if the users will be running this program (under their own user IDs), and *it* needs access to the files, then *they* need access to them too.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the programme is running as another user (i.e. the user only interacts with it but they aren't running it).